# Vertical scrollbar for a column of unknown height

Tags: html, css, height, scrollbar

I'm building a website that has a layout similar to [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com): a header, a sidebar on the left and a map on the right.

On the Google Maps website, when the content of the sidebar exceeds the height of the screen, a vertical scrollbar appears next to it (e.g. if you type 'restaurant' in the search box). I'm trying to achieve a similar effect and have tried various options, but nothing seems to work the right way. Setting the height of the sidebar to `auto` or `100%` does not work since the sidebar does not start at the top of the page - the vertical scrollbar is either too short and does not reach the bottom of the page (in the case of `auto` height) or too long and exceeds the height of the page (in the case of `100%` height). I think Google uses JS to calculate the height of the sidebar.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

You can make the left hand column a div with css that contains this:

```
overflow: scroll
```

If there is any overflow, a scrollbar will appear and that div will be scrollable.  You'll need to wrap all content in a fixed-width div so that you don't get horizontal scrollbars as well.

Edit:  An Example.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #example{
        overflow: scroll;
        height: 200px;
        width: 100px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #000;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example">Hello, World!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, if you replace "Hello, World!" with:

```
Line One<br />
Line Two<br />
Line Three<br />
Line Four<br />
Line Five<br />
Line Six<br />
Line Seven<br />
Line Eight<br />
Line Nine<br />
Line Ten<br />
```

You should get the scrolling action as soon as the text is too long to fill the div.

Comment: If this is the answer, I hate you. I thought it up an hour ago and swore it had to be more complicated than this.

Comment: in my case the problem is the column height is not known.

Comment: yulka:  Just set the div height to 100%.  It will then take up 100% of the available space, and scrolling will occur after that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using ui.layout jquery plugin, it works perfectly for me: http://layout.jquery-dev.net/index.html